# How to deploy a maven repository on gitlab to heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku, continuous-integration, gitlab

I created a .gitlab-ci.yml file and tried to deploy my maven repository on gitlab to heroku. Unfortunately I don't understand how to do this without the heroku-cli (which I could not install on gitlab).
The build process and test process is not failing but the deployment process is due to my lack of information about how it exactly works.

The yml file I created looks like this:

```
before_script:
  - apk update && apk add git 
  - apk update && apk add openjdk8
  - apk update && apk add maven
  - git --version

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - heroku git:remote -a NAME_OF_MY_HEROKUAPP
    - git push heroku master
  only:
    - master
```